# How to display the sum of values ​of this response body no Postman

Tags: json, testing, postman

I need a test that shows the result of the sum of the value field
for the response body below and shows it on the postman's console,
with the number of value in the response body being dynamic:

> the result of the sum of the values ​​below: "value": 108.45 "value":
> 147.28 "value": 87.70 "value": 20.00 "value": 75.40 "value": 87.70 "value": 147.28 "value": 87.70**

```
 {
    "detalhes": {
        "respostaDetalhe": [
            {
                "origem": "PAY",
                "path": "BITO",
                "nivel": 1,
                "chaveFonte": "VendaCanceladaDebito",
                "status": {
                    "codigo": "S00001",
                    "mensagem": "Operação realizada com sucesso",
                    "origem": "PAY",
                    "detalhes": {
                        "detalhe": []
                    }
                },
                "valuees": {
                    "detalhe": [
                        {
                            "niveisAnteriores": {
                                "nivel": []
                            },
                            "conteudos": {
                                "conteudo": [
                                    {
                                        "identificadores": {
                                            "identificador": [
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CUPOM",
                                                    "x": "8211184686-8241102617"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CHAVE_LINHA",
                                                    "x": "TOTAL_VENDA_CANC_DEBITO"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "value": 108.45
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        
                        {
                            "niveisAnteriores": {
                                "nivel": []
                            },
                            "conteudos": {
                                "conteudo": [
                                    {
                                        "identificadores": {
                                            "identificador": [
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CUPOM",
                                                    "x": "8211184688-8241102917"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CHAVE_LINHA",
                                                    "x": "TOTAL_VENDA_CANC_DEBITO"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "value": 147.28
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "niveisAnteriores": {
                                "nivel": []
                            },
                            "conteudos": {
                                "conteudo": [
                                    {
                                        "identificadores": {
                                            "identificador": [
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CUPOM",
                                                    "x": "8881016351-9041105200"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CHAVE_LINHA",
                                                    "x": "TOTAL_VENDA_CANC_DEBITO"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "value": 87.70
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "niveisAnteriores": {
                                "nivel": []
                            },
                            "conteudos": {
                                "conteudo": [
                                    {
                                        "identificadores": {
                                            "identificador": [
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CUPOM",
                                                    "x": "8881016193-9041103402"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CHAVE_LINHA",
                                                    "x": "TOTAL_VENDA_CANC_DEBITO"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "value": 20.00
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "niveisAnteriores": {
                                "nivel": []
                            },
                            "conteudos": {
                                "conteudo": [
                                    {
                                        "identificadores": {
                                            "identificador": [
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CUPOM",
                                                    "x": "8881015351-9041096206"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CHAVE_LINHA",
                                                    "x": "TOTAL_VENDA_CANC_DEBITO"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "value": 75.40
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "niveisAnteriores": {
                                "nivel": []
                            },
                            "conteudos": {
                                "conteudo": [
                                    {
                                        "identificadores": {
                                            "identificador": [
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CUPOM",
                                                    "x": "8881015000-9041093300"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CHAVE_LINHA",
                                                    "x": "TOTAL_VENDA_CANC_DEBITO"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "value": 87.70
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "niveisAnteriores": {
                                "nivel": []
                            },
                            "conteudos": {
                                "conteudo": [
                                    {
                                        "identificadores": {
                                            "identificador": [
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CUPOM",
                                                    "x": "8211184688-8241102919"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CHAVE_LINHA",
                                                    "x": "TOTAL_VENDA_CANC_DEBITO"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "value": 147.28
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "niveisAnteriores": {
                                "nivel": []
                            },
                            "conteudos": {
                                "conteudo": [
                                    {
                                        "identificadores": {
                                            "identificador": [
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CUPOM",
                                                    "x": "8881015351-9041096207"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "nome": "CHAVE_LINHA",
                                                    "x": "TOTAL_VENDA_CANC_DEBITO"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "value": 87.70
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What didn't work?

Comment: I tried to identify the first value field but without success, with the code below it returned undefined:


const response = pm.response.json();
const respostadetalhe = response.detalhes["respostaDetalhe"];
const nivel= respostadetalhe["1"];
console.log(nivel);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably lots more efficient ways of doing it but you could use something hacky like this:

```js
let detalheArray = _.get(pm.response.json(), 'detalhes.respostaDetalhe.0.valuees.detalhe'),
    valuesToSum = [];

_.each(detalheArray, (item) => {
    valuesToSum.push(item.conteudos.conteudo[0].value)
})
console.log(valuesToSum)
console.log(_.sum(valuesToSum))
```

Like I said, it's not the best solution but should get the values and add them together.